# Не могу вытащить и использовать Cookies при парсинге сайта через библиотеку requests Python

Tags: python, парсер, cookie, requests, jar

Всем привет. Есть проблема с использованием cookies в headers. Я кидаю get запрос на сайт 'https://www.mos.ru/' и получаю от туда cookie в формате RequestsCookieJar. Не знаю как дальше их использовать в headers и дополнять в процессе работы. Буду безумно благодарен.

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

mos_ru_get = session.get(url='https://www.mos.ru/')
print('MOS RU GET STATUS: ' + str(mos_ru_get.status_code))

value1 = mos_ru_get.cookies
print(value1)

headers = {
    'cookie': value1,    #Здесь проблема
    'referer': 'https://www.mos.ru/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.185 YaBrowser/20.11.2.78 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}

mos_password_get = session.get(url='https://login.mos.ru/sps/login/methods/password', headers=headers)
print('Logging: ' + str(mos_password_get.status_code))
```

Comment: Разве `session` не запоминает куки, полученные из ответа? Он должен сам их передавать в запросы

Comment: В том то и дело, что этого либо не происходит, либо есть иная защита данного сайта

Answer (score 2):

Куки немного по другому хранятся. Их не обязательно в хеадер пихать.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091976/python-requests-get-cookies

А авторизоваться на сайте можно примерно вот так:

```
req = requests.Session()
req.headers.update({
    'User-Agent': "MyUserAgent/1.0",
    'Content-Type': "application/json"
})
res = req.post(
    'https://login.mos.ru/sps/login/methods/password',
    data={
        'login': 'user_naem',
        'password': 'user_password',
        'notRememberMe': 0,
    }
)

if res.status_code == 200:
    print('Auth done.')
    print(req.cookies.get_dict())
```